# How to edit multiple lines in sed

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu, sed, gnu

I have 45 lines of code that need a sed command.  Due to the recent change in GNU all my scripts are breaking and need -std=legacy & -fallow-invalid-boz.  The only way I know how to do this is with sed.  I'm not a computer programmer and sed is simple and easy to understand.

These are a sample of my sed commands.

[image]

Is there a way to do all these sed commands in a loop or with sed itself.  If there is another editor that makes it easier I can try to learn that too.

I have tried this

```
for X in [24,28,32,36,40,45,49,53,56,60,64,68,69,73,74,79]
    sed -i '$Xs/= /= -std=legacy -fallow-invalid-boz /g' $HOME/WRF/Downloads/NCEPlibs/macros.make.linux.gnu
done
```

But I get the error:

> $ for X in [24,28,32,36,40,45,49,53,56,60,64,68,69,73,74,79] sed -i
> '$Xs/= /= -std=legacy -fallow-invalid-boz /g'
> $HOME/WRF/Downloads/NCEPlibs/macros.make.linux.gnu done bash: syntax
> error near unexpected token `sed' bash: syntax error near unexpected token` done'

Comment: Replace image with its text.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: See: `help for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing it like this is a lot smarter

```
y="24 28 32 36 40 45 49 53 56 60 64 68 69 73 74 79"
for X in $y; do
  sed -i "${X}s/= /= -std=legacy -fallow-invalid-boz /g" $HOME/WRF/Downloads/NCEPlibs/macros.make.linux.gnu
done
```

First of all, you forgot the **do** statement in **for** so the for statement will just fail before it can even execute.

Second of all [24,28,32,36,40,45,49,53,56,60,64,68,69,73,74,79] in not valid as **for** uses newlines and or white spaces to declare a new value going from left to right.

And last but not least, using **$X** is not valid in this example as bash reads it as **$Xs/** so using **${X}** is the correct way and of course using **""** instead of using **''** so **${X}** can actually be used.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't coded in almost a decade and I forgot all the syntax for for loops and how to do them.  I know this is super basic but for some reason I forgot it.

Comment: glad to be of service

Comment: Just a quick question @tomas. Why would you use double quotes " instead of single quotes '?